# SQLite LEFT JOIN count(*)?

Tags: join, sqlite, count, left-join

I need to join two tables (well, actually two views) so that for every selected row of the left view, there is a count of rows from the right view. That sounds to me like a LEFT JOIN, but in SQLite (this test [database](http://cl.ly/0o0s1z3E210u/download/umetest.umedb)) and a LEFT JOIN query:

```
SELECT TARGET.session_id session_id, TARGET.labeltype_id labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id label_id, count(SECONDARY.label_id) NOlabels 
FROM segment_extended TARGET LEFT JOIN segment_extended SECONDARY
WHERE TARGET.session_id = SECONDARY.session_id AND TARGET.lt_name= "Word" AND SECONDARY.lt_name ="Comments" 
AND ((SECONDARY.start <= TARGET.start AND TARGET.END <= SECONDARY.END) OR (TARGET.start <= SECONDARY.start AND SECONDARY.END <= TARGET.END))
AND TARGET.label != '' AND SECONDARY.label != '' 
GROUP BY TARGET.session_id,TARGET.labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id;
```

I get only a small subset of what I would expect:

```
2   3   3   1
2   3   9   1
```

A more extended query gives the correct result:

```
SELECT session_id, labeltype_id, label_id, max(NOlabels) NOlabels 
FROM (SELECT TARGET.session_id session_id, TARGET.labeltype_id labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id label_id, count(SECONDARY.label_id) NOlabels 
    FROM segment_extended TARGET , segment_extended SECONDARY
    WHERE TARGET.session_id = SECONDARY.session_id AND TARGET.lt_name= "Word" AND SECONDARY.lt_name ="Comments" 
    AND ((SECONDARY.start <= TARGET.start AND TARGET.END <= SECONDARY.END) OR (TARGET.start <= SECONDARY.start AND SECONDARY.END <= TARGET.END))
    AND TARGET.label != '' AND SECONDARY.label != '' 
    GROUP BY TARGET.session_id,TARGET.labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id
    UNION
    SELECT TARGET.session_id session_id, TARGET.labeltype_id labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id label_id, 0 NOlabels 
    FROM segment_extended TARGET
    WHERE TARGET.lt_name= "Word"
    AND TARGET.label != '' 
    GROUP BY TARGET.session_id,TARGET.labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id)
GROUP BY session_id, labeltype_id, label_id
ORDER BY session_id,labeltype_id, label_id


session_id  labeltype_id    label_id    NOlabels
2   3   2   0
2   3   3   1
2   3   4   0
2   3   5   0
2   3   7   0
2   3   8   0
2   3   9   1
2   3   10  0
```

but it seems unnecessarily complicated. What am I doing wrong with the left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a left join you have to count the null values from the left join as 0 records but still include them. You can accomplish this with a CASE construct in the inner query, then using the SUM aggregate function in the outer group-by.

```html
SELECT session_id, labeltype_id, label_id, sum(has_label) NOlabels
FROM (
    SELECT TARGET.session_id session_id, TARGET.labeltype_id labeltype_id, TARGET.label_id label_id, CASE WHEN SECONDARY.label_id is NULL then 0 else 1 END has_label
    FROM
        segment_extended TARGET
        LEFT JOIN
            segment_extended SECONDARY on
                TARGET.session_id = SECONDARY.session_id
                AND SECONDARY.lt_name ="Comments"
                AND ((
                    SECONDARY.start <= TARGET.start AND TARGET.END <= SECONDARY.END)
                    OR (TARGET.start <= SECONDARY.start AND SECONDARY.END <= TARGET.END))
                AND SECONDARY.label != ''
    WHERE TARGET.lt_name= "Word" AND TARGET.label != '')
GROUP BY session_id, labeltype_id, label_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join is not a left join.

A left join adds NULL values for the right table if there are no rows that match the join condition.
However, you query does not have a join condition, and the WHERE condition is not affect by the LEFT JOIN clause.

Replace WHERE with [ON](http://www.sqlite.org/syntax/join-clause.html).